# How can I use the Jenkins Copy Artifacts Plugin from within the pipelines (jenkinsfile)?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to find an example of using the Jenkins Copy Artifacts Plugin from within Jenkins pipelines (workflows).

Can anyone point to a sample Groovy code that is using it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If builds are not running in the same pipeline you can use direct `CopyArtifact` plugin, here is example: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/copying-artifacts-between-builds-jenkins-workflow and example code:

```
node {
   // setup env..
   // copy the deployment unit from another Job...
   step ([$class: 'CopyArtifact',
          projectName: 'webapp_build',
          filter: 'target/orders.war']);
   // deploy 'target/orders.war' to an app host
}
```

Answer (score 63):

With a declarative Jenkinsfile, you can use following pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('push artifact') {
            steps {
                sh 'mkdir archive'
                sh 'echo test > archive/test.txt'
                zip zipFile: 'test.zip', archive: false, dir: 'archive'
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'test.zip', fingerprint: true
            }
        }

        stage('pull artifact') {
            steps {
                copyArtifacts filter: 'test.zip', fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: env.JOB_NAME, selector: specific(env.BUILD_NUMBER)
                unzip zipFile: 'test.zip', dir: './archive_new'
                sh 'cat archive_new/test.txt'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Before version 1.39 of the CopyArtifact, you must replace second stage with following (thanks @Yeroc) :

```
stage('pull artifact') {
    steps {
        step([  $class: 'CopyArtifact',
                filter: 'test.zip',
                fingerprintArtifacts: true,
                projectName: '${JOB_NAME}',
                selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector', buildNumber: '${BUILD_NUMBER}']
        ])
        unzip zipFile: 'test.zip', dir: './archive_new'
        sh 'cat archive_new/test.txt'
    }
}
```

With `CopyArtifact`, I use '${JOB_NAME}' as project name which is the current running project.

Default selector used by `CopyArtifact` use last successful project build number, never current one (because it's not yet successful, or not). With `SpecificBuildSelector` you can choose '${BUILD_NUMBER}' which contains current running project build number.

This pipeline works with parallel stages and can manage huge files (I'm using a 300Mb file, it not works with stash/unstash)

> This pipeline works perfectly with my Jenkins 2.74, provided you have all needed plugins

Comment: Do you happen to know where this   step([  $class: 'CopyArtifact', syntax is documented? I think I remember it was generated by the Snippet generator, can't find it there now.. I'm especially wondering how you could use the parametrized build selector.

Comment: I saw an exemple [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin). About `SpecificBuildSelector`, I guessed it by analyzing the [plugin code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/copyartifact-plugin/tree/copyartifact-1.38.1/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/copyartifact)

Comment: As of version 1.39 of the CopyArtifact plugin you can use cleaner syntax:

    `copyArtifacts filter: 'test.zip', fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: '${JOB_NAME}', selector: specific('${BUILD_NUMBER}')`

Comment: If anyone has issues with Jenkins stating that it is unable to find the project to copy the artifact from, changing `projectName: '${JOB_NAME}', selector: specific('${BUILD_NUMBER}')` to `projectName: env.JOB_NAME, selector: specific(env.BUILD_NUMBER)` worked for me (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/55377899/758165).

Comment: copyArtifacts(projectName: <job-name>/<branch>') worked for me

Answer (score 34):

If you are using agents in your controller and you want to copy artifacts between each other you can use `stash`/`unstash`, for example:

```
stage 'build'
node{
   git 'https://github.com/cloudbees/todo-api.git'
   stash includes: 'pom.xml', name: 'pom'
}

stage name: 'test', concurrency: 3
node {
   unstash 'pom'
   sh 'cat pom.xml' 
}
```

You can see this example in this link:

https://dzone.com/refcardz/continuous-delivery-with-jenkins-workflow

Answer (score 1):

```
name = "/" + "${env.JOB_NAME}"
def archiveName = 'relNum'
try {
    step($class: 'hudson.plugins.copyartifact.CopyArtifact', projectName: name, filter: archiveName)
} catch (none) {
    echo 'No artifact to copy from ' + name + ' with name relNum'
    writeFile file: archiveName, text: '3'
}

def content = readFile(archiveName).trim()
echo 'value archived: ' + content
```

try that using copy artifact plugin