# Jenkins Pipeline Utility Steps - zip zipFile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to zip the folders which are created as output of my jenkins pipeline job using pipeline script. By googling i came to know the Jenkins

> Pipeline Utility Steps - zip zipFile

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-zip-code-create-zip-file to zip folders/files but could not get exact pipeline syntax to zip.

In my job workspace, I have a folder by name 'Test' which has 2 sub folders as 'Test1', 'Test2'. Each sub folder will have .dll files. So, I would like to zip entire 'Test' folder with all subfolder.

```groovy
node(Jenkinks_1)
{
    echo "ZIP"
    zip zipFile: 'Test.zip', dir:'C:\\workspace\\Build_Sample\\Test'
    echo "END - ZIP"
}
```

Below are the Console Output from Jenkins:

```
Started by user XXXXX
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkinks_1 in C:\workspace\Build_Sample
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
ZIP
[Pipeline] echo
END - ZIP
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Looking for some guidance to zip the folders using pipeline syntax. Appreciate your inputs.

I wanted to zip some files as output of my jenkins pipeline job

Answer (score 37):

First, try the same operation in stages and step, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46567313/6309):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('push artifact') {
            steps {
                sh 'mkdir archive'
                sh 'echo test > archive/test.txt'
                zip zipFile: 'test.zip', archive: false, dir: 'archive'
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'test.zip', fingerprint: true
            }
        }
        ...
    }
```

It uses [`archiveArtifacts`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/) to record the result.

If using an absolute path does now work, try a relative one (`'..'`)

As seen by the [OP Sri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7508713/sri), `zip zipFile` is part of, and requires the [**JENKINS Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin**](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps).
See "[Implemented Steps](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/docs/STEPS.md)".

---

Regarding the syntax to be used for multi-criteria file selection, [NicolasW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2204906/nicolasw) notes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352443/jenkins-pipeline-utility-steps-zip-zipfile/48353127#comment87579596_48353127) that the [documentation is vague](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/): "use glob ant-style syntax"...
He got it to work though,  with a basic coma separated syntax.
E.g.

```
zip zipFile: 'test.zip', archive: false, glob: 'config-/**/,scripts/**/*.*
```

But, as noted by [Tanvir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6676186/tanvir) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352443/jenkins-pipeline-utility-steps-zip-zipfile/48353127?noredirect=1#comment118334240_48353127), [issue 44078](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-44078) means you need to replace `zip` by:

```
                 script{ zip zipFile: 'test.zip', archive: false, dir: 'archive' }
```

Meaning you need to use a `script` block.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking to use Pipeline Utility Steps - zip zipFile using Pipeline Script instead of Declarative syntax. I did try with the above script.. but the build failed with following error messages:

Comment: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 8: Invalid parameter "zipFile", did you mean "label"? @ line 8, column 21.
                   zip zipFile: 'test.zip', archive: false, dir: 'archive'
                       ^

WorkflowScript: 8: Invalid parameter "archive", did you mean "url"? @ line 8, column 42.
        zip zipFile: 'test.zip', archive: f
                                 ^

WorkflowScript: 8: Invalid parameter "dir", did you mean "url"? @ line 8, column 58.
   : 'test.zip', archive: false, dir: 'arch

Comment: @Sri What version of Jenkins and Jenkins pipeline do you have?

Comment: I using Jenkins version - v2.73.2 and Jenkins pipeline - 2.5

Comment: Why do you use `archiveArtifacts`? You can archive the created zipfile directly when using `archive: true` in the zip step.

Comment: @IVleafclover I believe (2 years later, it is a bit fuzzy), this is to make the artifact available for download, as mentioned in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50130. zipFile does just a zip, archiveArtifacts is the Jenkins’s built-in support for storing "artifacts", which is important to make them available as a result of a pipeline.

Comment: @VonC Thanks for the answer. `zip zipFile: 'test.zip', archive: true, dir: 'archive'` will zip and archive the zip file in Jenkins artifacts. That way it is not necessary to use the `archiveArtifacts` command.
Nevermind your original answer is working fine and two years after your original answer my comment tend to be irrelevant.

Comment: Currently in declarative pipeline,  `zip` command does not work as documentation. It fails giving error message **Invalid parameter "zipFile"** . To make it work change the code to `script{ zip zipFile: 'test.zip', archive: false, dir: 'archive' } ` . This problem is addressed in [https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-44078](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-44078)

Comment: @Tanvir Thank you. I have edited the answer to include your comment for more visibility.

Answer (score 11):

Was able to Zip after installing the `Pipeline Utility Steps` plugin.

Comment: Interesting, so it wasn't working just because the plugin was not installed?

Comment: Yes, after installing the Pipeline Utility Steps plugin Zip command was working.

Comment: OK, I have completed my answer accordingly, with some links.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this because zip was ... not installed on the host.
Reminder to self : If you need zip, install it first.
`sudo yum install zip`

Answer (score 1):

you can just use sh (jenkins server need install zip);

```
 sh '''
            zip -r  algo.zip algo
 '''
```

pipeline script like this

```
node {
    stage('Clean'){
        cleanWs()
    }
    stage('Checkout') {
       git branch: 'develop', url: 'ssh://user@ip:29418/prj.git'
    }
    stage('Zip') {
        dir('algo-python') {
            sh '''
            zip -r  algo.zip algo
            '''
       }
    }
    stage('Upload zip'){
        dir('algo-python') {
            sh '''
                source /etc/profile
                export HADOOP_USER_NAME=dev
                hdfs dfs -put -f algo.zip /user/dev/zipfile/
            '''
        }
    }
}
```