# Zip a directory in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I keep getting this error: **"No signature of method: zip.call()"**

This is the code i am running in Jenkins pipeline :

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
       stage("test..")
       {
            steps
            {
             zip dir: '', glob: '', zipFile: 'testz.zip'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the zip step appear in sample steps in pipeline syntax, so not sure why this failing. I need to zip my source code folder.

Pipeline Utility Steps plugins is installed :
[image]

Comment: Have you installed the "pipeline utility steps" plugin? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48386777/6509

Comment: Yes, added image above

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
       stage("test.."){
          steps{
             script{
                    zip archive: true, dir: '', glob: '', zipFile: 'testz.zip'
             }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#zip-create-zip-file

Comment: Does this work when we run a pipeline using a container ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap `zip` step with `script {}`

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("test..") {
            steps {
                script {
                    zip dir: '', glob: '', zipFile: 'testz.zip'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```