# Jenkins CopyArtifact step - Unable to find project for artifact copy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843215/how-can-i-use-the-jenkins-copy-artifacts-plugin-from-within-the-pipelines-jenki), I'm trying to test this pipeline code in my environment:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('push artifact') {
            steps {
                sh '[ -d archive ] || mkdir archive'
                sh 'echo test > archive/test.txt'
                sh 'rm -f test.zip'
                zip zipFile: 'test.zip', archive: false, dir: 'archive'
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'test.zip', fingerprint: true
            }
        }

        stage('pull artifact') {
            steps {
                sh 'pwd'
                sh 'ls -l'
                sh 'env'
                step([  $class: 'CopyArtifact',
                        filter: 'test.zip',
                        projectName: '${JOB_NAME}',
                        fingerprintArtifacts: true,
                        selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector', buildNumber: '${BUILD_NUMBER}']
                ])
                unzip zipFile: 'test.zip', dir: './archive_new'
                sh 'cat archive_new/test.txt'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it gives the error message:

```
ERROR: Unable to find project for artifact copy: test
This may be due to incorrect project name or permission settings; see help for project name in job configuration.
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I fix his pipeline code?

Answer (score 41):

If you enable authorization(like rbac), you must grant permission 'Copy Artifact' to the project. In project configuration, General -> Permission to Copy Artifact, check the box and set the projects that can copy the artifact

Comment: Great answer. If it were not for you I don't know how many hours I would have spent to figure this out. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can set multiple project names with comma separated values.  You can also use * as a wildcard.

Comment: I have the same problem, I set permission and still have the error

Comment: or, `copyArtifactPermission('*');` in the options section of the Jenkinsfile.

Comment: I had to install the Authorize Project plugin and enable it per project

Answer (score 10):

Rather than using `projectName: '${JOB_NAME}'`, what worked for me is using `projectName: env.JOB_NAME`. I.e. your complete copy-artifacts step would look like this:

```
step([  $class: 'CopyArtifact',
        filter: 'test.zip',
        projectName: env.JOB_NAME,
        fingerprintArtifacts: true,
        selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector', buildNumber: env.BUILD_NUMBER]
])
```

Or using the more modern syntax:

```
copyArtifacts(
    filter: 'test.zip',
    projectName: env.JOB_NAME,
    fingerprintArtifacts: true,
    selector: specific(env.BUILD_NUMBER)
)
```