# Jenkins Copy Artifact "Unable to find a build for artifact copy from ..."

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to copy the artifacts from one build (`Coverity Test`), to another build (`MainBuild`).

`MainBuild` uses a declarative pipeline. I have added the following step to build `Coverity Test` as the final step in `MainBuild`.

```
stage('Coverity Test') {
    when { expression { params.CoverityReport ==true } }
    steps{
        build job: 'Coverity Test',
        parameters: [
            string(name: 'COVERITY_TOOL_HOME',
                  value: '/home/coverity/cov-analysis-linux64-2020.03'),
            string(name: 'GIT_BRANCH', value: "${env.PROJ_GIT_BRANCH}")
        ]

        copyArtifacts filter: 'CoverityCrit*Issues.txt', fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: 'Coverity Test', selector: specific ('${BUILD_NUMBER}')
    }        
}
```

The files CoverityCrit*Issues are created in a script through the Coverity Test build, I have confirmed that these files display as artifacts of the Coverity Test in Jenkins.

The `copyArtifacts` command returns an error **"ERROR: Unable to find a build for artifact copy from: Coverity Test"**

[I used this as an example to create the copyArtifacts command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36843215/how-can-i-use-the-jenkins-copy-artifacts-plugin-from-within-the-pipelines-jenki)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have single quotes around specific ('${BUILD_NUMBER}'), so the variable isn't expanded, but you don't need quotes or ${}, just do:
specific(BUILD_NUMBER)

Comment: Also,  value: "${env.PROJ_GIT_BRANCH}" can be just:  value: env.PROJ_GIT_BRANCH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside

```
selector: specific ('${BUILD_NUMBER}')
```

You need to use double quotes "" instead of single quotes ''.